# one bug in my code, I used Classes in python and define some functions inside but the values that passed to functions are not accurate

Tags: python

I am beginner on python and OOP. This is my first class code.
I wrote below python code and it will run, The Code is about 3 string that user enter them and the code check if these strings are valid or invalid(string are valid if string's length are between 1 to 50) But there is an issue on my code. I got always default values when I run my code. I think there is a problem on set_string functions. But I am not sure.
I would be appreciate for any help

Code:

```
class TripleString:
  string1=""
  string2=""
  string3=""
  Max_Len=50
  Min_Len=1
  def __init__(self,string1="Undefined1",string2="Undefined2",string3="Undefined3"):
    if(TripleString.get_string1_from_user()):
      self.string1=string1
    if(TripleString.get_string2_from_user()):
      self.string2=string2
    if(TripleString.get_string3_from_user()):
      self.string3=string3

  def valid_string(str):
    if(len(str)<TripleString.Min_Len or len(str)>TripleString.Max_Len):
      return False
    else:
      return True

  def set_string1(str1):
    if(TripleString.valid_string(str1)):
      TripleString.string1=str1
      print("String set")
      return True
    else:
      print("string not set since the len is not valid")
      return False

  def get_string1_from_user():
    str=input("STR1:")
    if(TripleString.set_string1(str)):
      return True
    else:
      return False

  def set_string2(str2):
    if(TripleString.valid_string(str2)):
      TripleString.string2=str2
      print("String set")
      return True
    else:
      print("string not set since the len is not valid")
      return False

  def get_string2_from_user():
    str=input("STR2:")
    if(TripleString.set_string2(str)):
      return True
    else:
      return False

  def set_string3(str3):
    if(TripleString.valid_string(str3)):
      TripleString.string3=str3
      print("String set")
      return True
    else:
      print("string not set since the len is not valid")
      return False

  def get_string3_from_user():
    str=input("STR3:")
    if(TripleString.set_string3(str)):
      return True
    else:
      return False



x=TripleString()

print(x.string1,x.string2,x.string3)
```

Output1:

```
STR1: String1
String set
STR2: String2
String set
STR3: String3
String set
Undefined1 Undefined2 Undefined3
```

output2:

```
STR1: strin1stringstringstringstringstringstringstringstringstringstringstringstringstringstring
string not set since the len is not valid
STR2: string2
String set
STR3: string3
String set
 Undefined2 Undefined3
```

But I expect the output for

> ```
>                         1st one : string1 string2 string3
>
>                         2nd one: undefined1  string2 string3
> ```

Appreciated!

Updated code for set_string1:

```
  def set_string1(self,str1):
    if(TripleString.valid_string(str1)):
      self.string1=str1
      print("String set")
      return True
    else:
      print("string not set since the len is not valid")
      return False

  def get_string1_from_user():
    str=input("STR1:")
    if(TripleString.set_string1(str)):
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

output:

```
> STR1: kiarash Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line
> 71, in <module>   File "python", line 8, in __init__   File "python",
> line 32, in get_string1_from_user TypeError: set_string1() missing 1
> required positional argument: 'str1'
```

Comment: The variables without `self.` in front (like `string1`) are local to a function (here: `__init__`) and can't be set in another function (here: `set_string...`).

Comment: The second output do not show first string since your code doesn't let any string more 50 chars

Comment: Thank You Michael, So do you know how can I fix it? how can I set value for string1 and...?

Comment: Thank you Christiano, I know that, do you have any way to fix the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned strings to the undefined on **init** every time . You need to use self on all defs. I updated your code here.
I hope it will work for you.

```
class TripleString:
  Max_Len=50
  Min_Len=1
  def __init__(self,string1="Undefined1",string2="Undefined2",string3="Undefined3"):
    if(TripleString.get_string1_from_user(self)):
      print("in init, string1=", string1)
    else:
      self.string1=string1
    if(TripleString.get_string2_from_user(self)):
      print("in init, string2=", string2)
    else:
      self.string2=string2
    if(TripleString.get_string3_from_user(self)):
      print("in init, string3=", string3)
    else:
      self.string3=string3

  def valid_string(self,str):
    if(len(str)<TripleString.Min_Len or len(str)>TripleString.Max_Len):
      return False
    else:
      return True

  def set_string1(self,str1):
    if(self.valid_string(str1)):
      self.string1=str1
      print("String set to",str1)
      return True
    else:
      print("string not set since the len is not valid")
      return False
  def set_string2(self,str2):
    if(self.valid_string(str2)):
      self.string2=str2
      print("String set to",str2)
      return True
    else:
      print("string not set since the len is not valid")
      return False
  def set_string3(self,str3):
    if(self.valid_string(str3)):
      self.string3=str3
      print("String set to",str3)
      return True
    else:
      print("string not set since the len is not valid")
      return False
  def get_string1_from_user(self):
    str=input("STR1:")
    print("in get_str1 from user, str=", str)
    if(self.set_string1(str)):
      return True
    else:
      return False
  def get_string2_from_user(self):
    str=input("STR2:")
    print("in get_str2 from user, str=", str)
    if(self.set_string2(str)):
      return True
    else:
      return False
  def get_string3_from_user(self):
    str=input("STR3:")
    print("in get_str3 from user, str=", str)
    if(self.set_string3(str)):
      return True
    else:
      return False

x=TripleString()
print(x.string1,x.string2,x.string3)
```

Output1:

```
STR1: Sample1
in get_str1 from user, str= Sample1
String set to Sample1
in init, string1= Undefined1
STR2: Sample2
in get_str2 from user, str= Sample2
String set to Sample2
in init, string2= Undefined2
STR3: Sample3
in get_str3 from user, str= Sample3
String set to Sample3
in init, string3= Undefined3
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
```

output2:

```
STR1: Sample1
in get_str1 from user, str= Sample1
String set to Sample1
in init, string1= Undefined1
STR2: uduahydaugdadhjksahdjkahsjkdhasjdhjksahdjkashdjksahdjkashjkdsahkjdhjksahdjksad
in get_str2 from user, str= uduahydaugdadhjksahdjkahsjkdhasjdhjksahdjkashdjksahdjkashjkdsahkjdhjksahdjksad
string not set since the len is not valid
STR3: sample3
in get_str3 from user, str= sample3
String set to sample3
in init, string3= Undefined3
Sample1 Undefined2 sample3
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up class bound variables and function calls (those starting with `TripleString.`) with object bound variables and calls (starting with `self.`) and local variables (starting with nothing).

If possible you should use object bound vars and calls. This first needs to prepend the parameter list of each method (including `__init__`) with a `self` parameter, like e.g.

```
def set_string1(self, str1):
```

You can then set an object bound variable like e.g.

```
self.string1 = str1
```

and refer to it in another function to e.g. print it:

```
print(self.string1)
```

A legitimate use for class bound variables are `TripleString.Min_Len` and `TripleString.Max_Len` (assuming they are the same for all objects of this class).

So `valid_string(str)` doesn't need to know the particular object and can be a class bound (static) method. To declare this, write the function as:

```
@staticmethod
def valid_string(str):
```

The method can then be called either as `TripleString.valid_string(...)` or even as `self.valid_string(...)` although it doesn't care about the particular object.

Comment: Thank you Micheal, I did it but it give me another error that set_string have 1 missing argument. I added updated code and out put to the question.

Comment: I am a little beginner in python

Comment: @kiarash The call `TripleString.set_string1(str)` is only valid if `set_string1` would be a class-bound method. The call wouldn't transmit the particular object on which the operation should happen. Replace it by `self.set_string1(str)`. This object-bound call is internally translated to something like `TripleString.set_string1(self, str)` where `self` is the particular object of class `TripleString` you want to operate on. Additionally `get_string1_from_user` must get a `self` as parameter as well and called in the same way.